# Is NETWORK SERVICE part of the INTERACTIVE group in windows?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, permissions

Is the NETWORK SERVICE user considered part of the INTERACTIVE windows group?

I have IIS6 Application Pools running using NETWORK SERVICE identity so I want to know if they'll get permissions granted to INTERACTIVE

Answer (score 1):

No. Network Service is not a member of INTERACTIVE. Only users currently logged on interactively (LogonType = 2) are dynamically added to this group.